# Tensorflow -- Custom Op -- Pass parameter as mutable objects (like pass by reference)

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, pass-by-reference

I try to develop a custom op in tensorflow during which I change values belonging to the input-tensor, and which after the op is finished should still reflects these changes.

The challenge is, that python passes the function parameters by assignment (== immutable type in our case), and thus blocks me from accessing the data I actually want to access in the op.

.

Minimal Working Example:

**test_script.py**

```
img = imread("some image path");
img = ((img_gt[:, : , 0:3]).flatten()).astype('float32')

img[0] = 50
print "First time (start value): ", img[0]

Custom_Loss_Module = tf.load_op_library('some shared library')

with tf.Session(''):
    Custom_Loss_Module.custom_loss(img)
    print "Fourth time (after custom op): ", img[0]
```

**custom_op_main.cpp**

```
REGISTER_OP("CustomLoss")
    .Input("mat: float")


class CustomLossOp : public OpKernel
{
    public:
        explicit CustomLossOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}


        void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override
        {
            Tensor & tensor_img = const_cast<Tensor &>(context->input(0));

            float* pointer_img = reinterpret_cast<float*>(const_cast<char*>((tensor_img.tensor_data()).data()));

            std::cout << "Second time (in op): " << pointer_img[0] << "\n" << std::flush;

            pointer_img[0] = 100;

            std::cout << "Third time (in op): " << pointer_img[0] << "\n" << std::flush;
        } 
};
```

**Output:**

```
First time (start value):       50
Second time (in op):            50
Third time (in op):             100
Fourth time (after custom op):  50   <-- I want to see a 100 here :(
```

.

Now as mentioned above, I know where this behaviour comes from, and I know that this is to be expected. However, I would like to find a way so that the change from 50 to 100 (done in the custom op) is mutable, and thus is being reflected by the img-tensor once the custom op is finsihed. In C++-terms: I want to pass the function parameter by reference and not by assignment.

.

**What I tried so far:**

I tried to use the standard python trick and pass the parameter as a list, as a list is mutable. Example:

**test_script.py**

```
img = imread("some image path");
img = ((img_gt[:, : , 0:3]).flatten()).astype('float32')

img[0] = 50
print "First time (start value): ", img[0]

Custom_Loss_Module = tf.load_op_library('some shared library')

with tf.Session(''):
    Custom_Loss_Module.custom_loss([img])
    print "Fourth time (after custom op): ", img[0]
```

.

However, I did not got it to work, and following this discussion: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9334, I also believe that a custom op cannot take a list as an input parameter (even so the documentation mentions that it can ... :S. See "Attr types" at this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op)

.

So could anyone please assist me with this problem? - Thx in advance :)

Comment: This is a great question, is there by any chance any solution to this after since the original posting date?

Answer (score 0):

Mutation of tensorflow tensors is not allowed by the framework, so you're getting weird undefined behavior. Do not do that; tensorflow tensors are immutable.

Instead, make an op which takes an input tensor and returns an output tensor which is a copy of the input but with some things changed. Or use variables (but that will lose differentiability of your computation).